# Android View type at runtime

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app which used a GridView to display a set of items. Each of these items is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.myapp.customviews.Tile
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tile" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my `OnItemClickHandler` I want to check if the type of the View with id `R.id.tile` (My custom View class mentioned above) is `com.example.myapp.customviews.EmptyTile`. This class is a child of the Tile class.

Currently I'm checking if the class is an EmptyTile as follows:

```
LinearLayout tileLayout = (LinearLayout) gridView.getChildAt(position);
if (EmptyTile.class.isInstance(tileLayout.findViewById(R.id.tile))) {
    Log.d("myappDebug", "Correct instance!");
}
```

I have tried checking using `instanceof` and `tileLayout.findViewById(position).getClass() == EmptyTile.class` but these also don't work. At runtime, my view is just a Tile View and not an EmptyTile View.

How can I check if my View is actually an instance of the EmptyTile class?

Answer (score 0):

instanceof must work. But, in your XML, you define the view to be of type com.example.myapp.customviews.Tile, so why do you expect it to be an EmptyTile?
If you use EmptyTile (with the correct package of course) in the XML, the instanceof check and the other options will work.

Comment: I'm using Tile in the XML instead as all but one instance will be Tile instances. Would it be possible to read the instance without having to use a different XML for the EmptyTile?

Comment: Not, I donlt think so. When you define a tag in an XML with a concrete view subclass, it will be instantiated with that class, that's why it is Tile. You could better describe what you are trying to do: are your Tiles dynamically created, or do you define all of them in the XML as child of some layout? If the latter is the case, just define Tile when you want Tile, and EmptyTile otherwise.

Comment: My tiles are dynamically created so I think the only way to do it would be with two layouts. Thanks!

Comment: Well if you create them dynamically, then you create Tiles or EmptyTiles, and then instanceof will just work.